# Does Christianity prohibit astrology?

Tags: biblical-basis

Can Christians learn astrology? I read the introduction on Wikipedia, which said that astrology has been accepted for a period of time.

1.) “I will never forget sitting in Sunday school while the preacher taught us about the three wise men. I wondered how they could have known that Jesus would be born just by following the special shining star in the sky that was guiding them. It was years later when I realized that the three wise men were astrologers. This information brought me peace as I began my astrological counseling journey.”

Who are these three wise men and what is their relationship with Jesus?

Why is it said that after knowing that these three wise men are also astrologers, it means that Christianity does not prohibit astrology?

2.) "Many Christians are opening up their minds to things that they have never dreamed of before. According to a recent study, nearly 30 percent of Catholics stated that they believed in astrology. Among white evangelicals there was 13 percent that professed a belief in astrology. From my personal experiences working as a licensed clinical social worker, I find that many of my clients are becoming more interested in astrology as a tool for self-awareness.”

Why do so many Christians like astrology? What do they think is the basis for Christianity not to prohibit astrology?

3.) “There is a tendency for people to neglect God and put their faith in psychics and mediums completely and this is what the Bible warns against in some verses. They were warned that it is a tool to be used in moderation, when needed, but to never ignore God and depend solely on an astrologer for your answers. A Christian mystic, Edgar Cayce stated, “Astrology is fact, but there is no greater power over man than his own will.” God gave us free will to make our own choices and as Cayce believed the planets energies have an effect upon us by influencing our inclinations, tendencies are urges. Cayce himself was a devout Christian.

PS: A kind of fortune-telling is popular in our country, inferring the fate of a person's life based on the date of birth.
According to the fortune tellers' speculation, I will never stay in the same room all my life, which means that I will often move to the dormitory and live in different places.
My unlucky year has also been accurately calculated. The fact that I was thrown into prison by the intelligence agency was also calculated. I believe that fortune-telling is effective, but I don’t want to give up fortune-telling.

Comment: There is a difference between watching the heavens for a sign which has been prophesied and the act of superstitiously attributing events to random, atronomical observations. I think the question needs to be scoped with some defining detail.

Comment: “Christianity” is too broad. Please consider changing this question to ask about a specific denomination or biblical support for rejecting astrology.

Comment: An unusual book you might enjoy reading is Kenneth C. Fleming's book, "God's Voice in the Stars." https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1209563.God_s_Voice_In_The_Stars. Don

Answer (score 3):

What warning does God give about astronomical objects?

> And when you look up to the sky and see the sun, the moon and the stars — all the heavenly array — do not be enticed into bowing down to them and worshiping things the LORD your God has apportioned to all the nations under heaven.
> — Deuteronomy 4:19 (NIV)

God created all the heavens and everything in them.
Objects have no spiritual power, and treating them as being able to affect one's life is a form of idolatry, even if one doesn't literally bow down to them.

What does God think of astrologers and their worth?

> All the counsel you have received has only worn you out!
> Let your astrologers come forward, those stargazers who make predictions month by month, let them save you from what is coming upon you.
> Surely they are like stubble; the fire will burn them up.
> They cannot even save themselves from the power of the flame.
> These are not coals for warmth; this is not a fire to sit by.
> -- Isaiah 47:13–14 (NIV)

The first two sentences are ironic.
Astrologers can't help you, and they themselves will eventually be burned to ashes.

Does God want you to even learn anything about astrology?

> This is what the LORD says: “Do not learn the ways of the nations or be terrified by signs in the heavens, though the nations are terrified by them.
> For the practices of the peoples are worthless …
> — Jeremiah 10:2–3 (NIV)

Comment: But why some Christian believe astrology?

Comment: @linliang asks "*But why [do] some Christian believe [in] astrology?*".  One might as well ask why some Muslims drink alcohol, why some Jews eat pork, why some Buddhists fight in wars, why some Hindus eat beef, why some Atheists say "OMG", why some Mormons drink coffee, … . The question was about what is allowed or prohibited, not about what is practiced.

Answer (score 0):

The Magi said : We saw his star when it rose and have come to worship him.” (Mtt 2:2) . They did not say to have seen his `constellation 'which is the base for astrology. Assuming that they were astrologers, would be out of place.

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes, but the three magi weren't worshippers of God, so using them as role models may not be wise.

The three "Wise Men" were magi, the priests of the Zoroastrian religion, from whose name the English language derives words like "magic" and "magician", and whose religion believes in the existence of two equally powerful gods, one good and one evil, though it's my understanding that they only actually worship the former one.

While magi were, in general, well known for their knowledge of astronomy, since they were members of a religion that doesn't worship the Abrahamic God, and there's no mention of their conversion to any Abraham's religion, it seems unwise to emulate their example as a Christian.